# Application is not displaying under Application Permissions in BB 10

Tags: permissions, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades, blackberry-qnx

I'm implementing a BlackBerry 10 Cascade application. There I have given following permissions in the ***bar-descriptor.xml***.

```
<permission>run_when_backgrounded</permission>
<permission>access_internet</permission>
```

Then I clean, build and run the application using QNX Momentics IDE. Next go to the ***System Settings*** -> ***Security and Privacy*** -> ***Application Permissions*** and select "***Permissions All***" from the drop-down. But I cannot see my application listed there. I am using *Dev Alpha device* for my testing. I have used even *Device-Release* for *Build Configuration*.

What could be the mistake I have done?

Comment: I don't know why it happens, but I have the same behaviour with one of my application, which needs the ``access_internet`` permission. I can't see it in the application list. However, I can see another one, installed via Momentics too, which needs location-related permissions...

Comment: I got a response from [BlackBerry forum] (http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Native-Development/Application-is-not-displaying-under-Application-Permissions-in/td-p/2537667)

Comment: Good to know :-) Maybe post it as an answer here, so users finding your question see it's solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a response from BlackBerry Forum. The place I've mentioned in the question lists applications that needs user permissions only. Other applications, whose permissions listed in the `bar-descriptor.xml` don't need user confirmation, aren't listed there. You can see the answer given by *peter9477* in BB forum from [here](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Native-Development/Application-is-not-displaying-under-Application-Permissions-in/td-p/2537667).